# IE (or other) add input to web form and disable field

Tags: html, forms, dom, iframe

We use Cisco's Unified Attendant web interface at work and we have an occasional issue where the user sits down to answer calls for the company and out of habit sees the "extension" field and enters their own instead of the receptionist extension.

Is there any way that I can take control of this field and input info and then disable the field?  To my knowledge we do have control of the server, but not the source.

- While I don't believe I can do this with simply a page and some
  js.... Is it possible to tell IE or FF to load a JavaScript file on
- EVERY that it returns? If this isn't possible is something like this
  possible with either a FF or IE extension/plugin? Is there a purely
- js/html method I'm not thinking of?

I've looked into the JavaScript/html option using iframes, but beyond that I wasn't sure where to look next.

Comment: Are you opposed to scripting?  You can create a script to launch IE and then take control of the DOM and fill in values.

Comment: I'm not opposed to anything as long as I can load the page and set a single field and disable it.  Basically I just need something that can manipulate a single url (and it's contents) and then ignore everything else.  I really just didn't know where to go after I had looked at iframes.  Just wasn't sure on language/path to take/anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using javascript for the desktop.  You can easily create a shortcut to it and inform the people to use this specific shortcut.

```
var urlConstant = "http://www.google.com/";
var ie = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");

ie.visible = true;
ie.navigate(urlConstant);

while(ie.readystate != 4){
}

var document = ie.document;

document.getElementById("gbqfq").value = "stackoverflow";
```

Obviously, change the element id and the value to your liking.

You can also create it in vbscript.  This is the quickest & easiest way.